# Listbox items Saved in SQL Server while moving Items top to down and viceversa

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

In Windows forms

I have a listbox and two buttons UP and Down.. When I click one of the buttons, the list Item will move up or down, depending on which button was clicked.

My question is when I click `Down` button, the `listItem` will moving towards downside at the same time it will updated as same as listitems in run time.. I was trying a lot my code is shown below..

```
private void btndown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string myNextItem1 = frm2lstbx.Items[frm2lstbx.SelectedIndex + 1].ToString();

    string globalNextItem1 = "";

    {
        int a = frm2lstbx.Items.Count - 1;

        if (frm2lstbx.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an Item");
        }
        else if (frm2lstbx.SelectedIndex == a)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Items to move Lower side");
        }
        else
        {
            int i = 0;
            i = frm2lstbx.SelectedIndex;
            string currItem = "";
            string nextItem = "";
            globalNextItem1= frm2lstbx.Items[i + 1].ToString();
            currItem = frm2lstbx.SelectedItem.ToString();

            frm2lstbx.Items.Insert(i, globalNextItem1.ToString());
            MyDAL.UpdateData1(currItem, globalNextItem1);
            MyDAL.UpdateData1(globalNextItem1, currItem);
            frm2lstbx.Items.RemoveAt(i + 2);
         }
     }
  }
```

In `MYDAL` class I  have below method for `Updatedata` in SQL Server...

```
public static void UpdateData1(string UpdatedItem, string OldItem)
{
        string strSql = @" Update tbl_srs set [Description]='" + UpdatedItem + "' where [Description]='" + OldItem + "'";

        Utils.ExecuteSql(strSql);
}
```

Note: `Utils` is another class library which contains methods for executing sql commands and so on..

My problem is: SQL Server updating row below of the selected item correctly.. but selected item overwrite the same item... that's why entire listbox updated with same values of selected item...

For ex: I have taken i=0 indexed selected item...

When I click down button control goes to i=1 nd it will now selected item, so in SQL Server I updated i=1 indexed item with i =0 item..it updated correctly

after  i=0 indexed item  may not updated correctly..it overwrite the  same value ,which is in i=0Indexed item.

Comment: Your sql is subject to sql injection, think about fixing it. Parameterized queries can help you.

Comment: tel me clear descripition.....@peer